# Android Bundle extra is getting null keys

Tags: java, android, null, key, bundle

i am trying to do a simple information transition between activities.
The problem is, in the received activity I am getting stuck in `get.Extras() == null`

### here is the receive activity code:

```
helloName = (TextView) findViewById(surfaceName);
Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
String nome = extra.getString("keyName");
System.out.println(nome) ;   #PRINTING =null
helloName.setText("Olá "+nome);
```

### Here is my passing information Activity:

```
Editable nome = name.getText();
System.out.println(nome);
Intent intent = new Intent(HelloActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("keyName",nome);
System.out.println(intent.getExtras());
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Simple question does Editable is a String?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
   Editable nome = name.getText();
   System.out.println(nome);
   Intent intent = new Intent(HelloActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
   intent.putExtra("keyName",nome.toString());
   System.out.println(intent.getExtras());
   startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: TKS BRO, it Works